# Bash: var expansion confusion possibly due to IFS

Tags: bash, find, whitespace, variable-expansion, ifs

After reading about [getting files with spaces in the name using `find`](https://askubuntu.com/a/343753), I put together a small code chunk to grab all `.sh` files in a directory and make them executable:

```html
find . -type f -name '*.sh' -print0 | 
while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
  name=$(printf '%s\n' "$file" | sed "s|^\./||")
  echo $name
  if ! [[ -x $name ]] ; then
    chmod +x "${name}"
  fi
done
```

The third-to-last line gave me the most trouble. I went through all 3 permutations:

`chmod +x $name`
`chmod +x ${name}`
`chmod +x "${name}"`

I have two questions:

1. I'd like to know why the last one, and only the last one, worked. Does it have to do with the `IFS` bit set earlier?
2. If there's a simpler way to do this, what would it be? Again, it should grab all `.sh` files in the current directory -- all of which have spaces in their filenames -- and make them executable.

Comment: You should always quote variables, and even more so if they can contains whitespace or glob characters. As for a simpler way:  `find . -type f -name '*.sh' -exec chmod +x {} +`

Comment: One tic further: `find -name "*.sh" ! -executable -exec chmod +x {} +` only treats files, which aren't executable already. Note that finds (GNU-find) exec option makes treatment of white space superfluous.

Comment: I vote to reopen the question, because find offers options, which make the complicated treatment of white space superfluous, but find is not the topic of the linked answer.

Comment: We have whitespace in the filenames because they're generated, and used, by other systems on an OS X machine. Do the same rules for GNU-find / `exec` still apply?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you put a variable assignment at the beginning of a command, it only applies to that one command. So the `IFS` you set earlier was only used by the `read` command. The rest of the code uses the default `IFS`, which has whitespace as the field separator.

If you want the `IFS` setting to apply to all the code, you need to do it as a separate statement, not as a prefix of a command.

```
IFS=
find . -type f -name '*.sh' -print0 | 
while read -r -d '' file; do
  name=$(printf '%s\n' "$file" | sed "s|^\./||")
  echo $name
  if ! [[ -x $name ]] ; then
    chmod +x "${name}"
  fi
done
```

But in general you should quote your variables. Even if `IFS` is set, you will have problems if the variable contains wildcard characters, because wildcards are expanded after expanding non-quoted variables. Only leave variables unquoted if you actually need word splitting and globbing.